# Android Relative scales for multiple screen sizes

Tags: android, dimension

I wanted to know about how can I make an android app support multiple screen sizes. I have developed an app that looks fine on my 7'inch tablet but when I run the same app on my android cell phone (with a much smaller screen) everything goes out of proportion (the alignment, the size). Could anyone please help me solve this problem. Below is the code of on of the screens of my app that has some buttons and text on it. It looks well on a tablet but not on a cell phone. Could anyone make any change to the below code so that it becomes at least a starting point for me?

A snippet from my .xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/theme">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/scale_tv"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
<Button
        android:id="@+id/scales"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scale_home_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The .java file

```
package com.demo.uiwithrelativescales;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UIwithRelativeScales extends Activity {

    private Button scaleBtn;
    private Button graphBtn;
    private Button notesBtn;
    private Button photosBtn;
    private Button videosBtn;
    private Button audiosBtn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 1) // portrait
            setContentView(R.layout.portrait_layout);
        else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == 2) // landscape
            setContentView(R.layout.landscape_layout);


        int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        String toastMsg;
        switch(screenSize) {
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
                toastMsg = "Large screen";
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:
                toastMsg = "Normal screen";
                break;
            case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:
                toastMsg = "Small screen";
                break;
            default:
                toastMsg = "Screen size is neither large, nor normal or small";
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        scaleBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scales);
        graphBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.graphs);
        notesBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.notes);
        photosBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.photos);
        videosBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.videos);
        audiosBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.audios);


        TextView TV_userName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcome_user);

        TV_userName.setText("Current Screen Orientation is "+ 
                getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);

        // the Scale
        TextView scale_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scale_tv);
        scale_heading.setText("SCALES");
        scale_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        scale_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        scale_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        scale_heading.setTextSize(20);
        scale_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the Graph
        TextView graph_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.graph_tv);
        graph_heading.setText("GRAPHS");
        graph_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        graph_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        graph_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        graph_heading.setTextSize(20);
        graph_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the Notes
        TextView note_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.note_tv);
        note_heading.setText("NOTES");
        note_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        note_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        note_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        note_heading.setTextSize(20);
        note_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the Photos
        TextView photos_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.photos_tv);
        photos_heading.setText("PHOTOS");
        photos_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        photos_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        photos_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        photos_heading.setTextSize(20);
        photos_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the Videos
        TextView video_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.videos_tv);
        video_heading.setText("VIDEOS");
        video_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        video_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        video_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        video_heading.setTextSize(20);
        video_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        // the Audios
        TextView audio_heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.audios_tv);
        audio_heading.setText("AUDIOS");
        audio_heading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.homebtns_heading);
        audio_heading.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        audio_heading.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        audio_heading.setTextSize(20);
        audio_heading.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a more complete layout (are you using a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout?) and eg screenshots on the phone and the tablet to illustrate the problem? Note also that you don't need the if/then/else construct if you put the layout files (with the same name) in layout-port/ and layout-land/ (see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: @Marc I have made some changes to the .xml file and as regards the images, this site doesn't allow me to upload and says "You need at least 10 reputations to post images". Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options

**Flexible Layouts**

You have a lot of hardcoded sizes making your layouts inflexible. Use margins and weights so that the layout can be scaled by the framework.

**Multiple Layouts**

One option is to create different layouts for different screen sizes. 
You simply create multiple resource folders and have a layout file with the same name in each folder.

- res/layout-small
- res/layout-large
- res/layout-xlarge

*edit* [further reading](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

This option is good if you want a lot of control over how the layout scales. It is typically not the preferred option unless you want the components arranged in different manners (i.e. tablet vs phone layouts) because it requires maintaing multiple layout files.

**Simplify Layout**
By the way you layout could be a lot simpler for the same effect.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/theme">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scale_tv"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scales"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/scale_home_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Cyroxis. Is there any working example you could tell me as it would become easier for me to understand? I'd be grateful

Comment: @user238710 Can you be more specific as to what you are wanting? I would suggest reading over the link on supporting different size screens and asking clarifying questions.

Comment: I need a working example, no matter how small, so that I can play around with it and see the changes practically on my devices. I have gone through the link you provided, thanks for that, but I think they are mostly concepts, I don't understand how to use them in my code. I need to see those concepts working in some app/code which would be  easier for me to understand.